# Can't call this.setState inside an event listener

Tags: reactjs

```js
    loadMap() {

        const map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
            zoom: 8
        });

        this.setState({map:map}); // This Works!

        window.google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function( event ){
            this.setState( {lat : "a" }); // This Doesn't Work.
            
          });

        

    }
```

I tried to put it inside componentDidMount() function as suggested by someone else, still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be value of `this` is not same as outside of event listener as inside. A way around is, You can use the following way like taking value of `this` into some variable, then use it

```
loadMap() {

        const map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
            zoom: 8
        });

        this.setState({map:map}); // This Works!
        let self = this; // setting into a local variable
        window.google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function( event ){
            self.setState( {lat : "a" }); // Try this.
        });



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try an arrow-function:

```
window.google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', (event) => {
    this.setState( {lat : "a" });      
};
```